# Simple php mail header with variable

Tags: php, function, email

I cannot get this header to show the variable needed for some strange reason. I know its something very slight. I know that this works:

```
$headers .= 'Bcc: example@aol.com' . "\r\n";
```

Can someone please help me with this. FULL CODE:

```
<?php

if ($_POST){

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$message .= "<hr />Sent from your Website at example.com.";


$to = 'person@aol.com';
$from = $email;

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// THE EMAIL IS NOT SENDING THE SENDER OF THE EMAIL 
// the from and bcc do not work as needed!
// More headers, put on double quotes
$headers .= 'From:'.$from."\r\n";

$headers .= 'Bcc: '.$from."\r\n";


// send
if (mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
{
  echo "Message was successfully sent! $from";

} else {
echo "Something went wrong..";
}



} else {

}

?>
```

Comment: **$** missing from headers

Comment: You missed a dot after the closing quote and you missed the $ for defining the variable headers

Comment: sorry it was a mistyping. I have updated this question, it still doesn't work when I try putting a variable in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a dot (period) after your first 'Bcc: '.

it should be

```
  $headers .= 'Bcc: ' . $from . "\r\n";
```

UPDATE:

You need to use double quotes when using special characters like \r and \n.  In your original example code you used double quotes, but I see now with your full code that you're not actually using them, you're using single quotes.

Single quoted strings in PHP show special characters as literals.

So your lines should be

```
$headers .= 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: ' . $from . "\r\n";
```

Comment: sorry, that was a mistype on stack, i have updated the question. It still doesnt work for some strange reason!

Comment: Where are you looking at the header?  Bcc is STRIPPED OUT of the header on email clients.  That's the whole point.  So if you're checking there, you won't ever see it.

Comment: the email is not sending with the FROM or BCC, I have posted the full code, sorry for the confusion

Comment: I updated my answer.  You need to use double quotes when using special characters.

Comment: I add the double quotes and updated my code, however nothing is sending at all now. Please see above on what I changed. I have verified that the $from variable is working with the correct email address, however it is just not sending.

Comment: Your problem may be with either a) the $from variable not being set, or b) your smtp software may not be setup right.

Answer (score 0):

Use this will work perfectly:

```
$headers .= 'From:  "'.$from.'"' . "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

easiest and the best way

```
"From: ". $email. "\r\n";
```